# What dimension has space of m-linear map on n dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

What dimension has space of m-linear map on n dimensional space?
Display in a field with a vector space above it.

Comment: What's the range of your maps? If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, then you consider maps $f:V^m \rightarrow X$ which are linear in their arguments. But what is $X$? I suppose $X$ is another vector space. What's its dimension?